# Cron Job Failed on Google App Engine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I try to implement a Cron Job on Google App Engine. I created a Cron.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<cronentries>
<cron>
    <url>/PingS</url>
    <description>send status message every 15 mins</description>
    <schedule>every 15 minutes</schedule>
</cron>
</cronentries>
```

I should call the servlet PingS every 15 mins. But once I deploy on Google App Engine I receive no logs of my servlet (It is not call) and this when I check the status of my Cron on Google App Engine: it fails (2 secs late Failed).

I do not why it fails, and I cannot have or check log of it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution,

The Cron Job targets only the default project deployed on Google App Engine. As I deployed in a different version, the Servlet I created cannot be called.